# Serializing Oracle Row into XML

Tags: xml, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I’m building a table that logs SQL INSERT errors, so when a row violates a unique constraint, or there are too many values or anything is goofy we want to log that to a table. I thought of creating an XML column and just serializing the problem rows as XML but I am wondering if there is a way to serialize rw (the cursor variable) into XML without specifying the column names.

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR TABLE1
        IS
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLENAME) WHERE ROWNUM < 500;

BEGIN
        FOR rw IN TABLE1
        LOOP
              /*SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT rw FROM DUAL') doesn't work*/
        END LOOP;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
END;
```

The closest I’ve come is having to reselect it.

```
 SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLENAME) WHERE ID = ' || rw.id) FROM DUAL
```

but I shouldn't need to requery since I already have it right? Is there a way to just send rw to XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SYS_XMLGEN Oracle SQL Function.

```
create table mytab(n number, v varchar2(5));
insert into mytab values(1,'abc');
insert into mytab values(2,'def');
insert into mytab values(3,'ghi');
commit;

SELECT sys_XMLGen(n) AS "SerialNumber", 
       sys_XMLGen(v) AS "Text"
  FROM mytab;
```

Output:

```
SerialNumber    Text
<N>1</N>        <V>abc</V>
<N>2</N>        <V>def</V>
<N>3</N>        <V>ghi</V>
```

For further reading refer [OracleDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1600).

Comment: This does not answer the question. rw is a row inside a cursor how can I apply sys_xmlgen to the cursor variable?

Comment: Do you need a cursor. Why not execute the SQL directly?

Comment: As I explain in the original question. I am inserting rows into a table one by one, if there is an exception (unique constraint violations, too many values, etc ) I want to be able to analyze the record that created the exception. I cannot just query because I don't know if an insert is going to blow up unless I try it

Answer (score 0):

Create a view on your source table that contains the prepared XML column for logging.

```
create view v_mytab as 
select n, v,
XMLELEMENT("row",
               XMLFOREST(
                 n AS "n",
                 v AS "v" 
               )
         )   as xml_col
from mytab;

select * from v_mytab;

         N V     XML_COL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------- ----- ------------------------------
         1 abc   <row><n>1</n><v>abc</v></row>  
         2 def   <row><n>2</n><v>def</v></row>   
         3 ghi   <row><n>3</n><v>ghi</v></row>
```

Use the `XML_COL` in case of exception while processing the cursor.

If performance is your concern, note that you may use execption loggin also in the [`INSERT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#subhead3) statement.

insert into trgt (n,v)
select n,v from v_mytab
LOG ERRORS INTO errlog ('my_bad');

This will log all the row columns in teh exception table and you may present the XML in a view upon this table.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't way to send row to xml. You can try only with dynamic cursors.

```
select xmlserialize(document serialized) from xmltable('ROWSET/ROW' passing xmltype(
      cursor(select * from user_objects where rownum<10 /* your query */)
      ) columns serialized xmltype path '.');
```